# 'AudioAttributes()' not public in 'android.media.AudioAttributes'. Cannot be accessed from outside package

Tags: android

I'm getting an error mentioned below when I try to instantiate AudioAttributes for setting AudioAttributes inside the sound pool.

> 'AudioAttributes()' not public in 'android.media.AudioAttributes'.
>   Cannot be accessed from outside package

```
AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes  ().Builder().build();
```

I need help setting AudioAttributes in SoundPool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor for AudioAttributes is not public, you need to use `Builder` class which is a subclass nested inside `AudioAttributes`. Change your assignment to below

```
AudioAttributes audioAttributes= new AudioAttributes.Builder().build();
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer